# Pearson's coefficient and p-value. How do I work out proportions from this?

Tags: self-study, correlation, statistical-significance, pearson-r

My results of a Pearson's Correlation are shown below:

```
Pearson’s Correlation – Test for Association  
Pearson's product-moment correlation:
Test statistic: r = -0.1146235
Degrees of freedom = 363
Statistical significance: P = 0.02855
```

Reject null hypothesis, there is a small negative correlation between TV hours and the number of books read. Based on the negative $r^2$ value. 
The p-value is  ≤ 0.05.

What proportion of the variation in number of Books read has been explained by the variation in hours of TV watched?

My answer is r2= -0.01313854675 x 100% = 1.3% in favour of TV watching.

Is this correct?

Comment: $r^2$ and r and so on relate to the relationship between two (sometimes more, but here 2) variables; you seem to be after something else - but it isn't completely clear what; I am confused by your title and by "in favor of TV watching".

Comment: A group of approx 500 students were asked how many hours of TV they watched per week and the number of books read per month. H0 = There is no association between the hours of TV watched per week and the number of books read per month.
H1 = The greater the number of hours of TV watched per week, the less the number of books read per month.
H2 = The less the number of hours of TV watched per week, the greater the number of books read per month.
I am not quite sure how to work out from the results of the test how I can deduce how many hours of TV watching leads to x number of books read..etc.

Comment: You should look at the regression equation and think about what it means. Since this is self-study, I don't want to give the explicit answer.

Comment: Only 1.3% of one variable is represented in the other. And as r is so close to zero, one could I assume that the tiny negative association is negligible?

Comment: Hint: $r^2$ in this context cannot be negative, but $r$ can be.